# NSArray crashes the app when accessing it

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsarray

I have a problem with accessing/setting an object from/to a NSArray returned with the CFPreferencesCopyAppValue() method. My app crashes in this case whereas when I alloc/init it myself, everything works well.

```
 CFArrayRef cfArray;
    if ((cfArray = (CFArrayRef)CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(CFSTR("buttonsOrder"), appID))) {
        NSArray *castedArray = [(NSArray *)cfArray retain];
        NSLog(@"castedArray : %@", castedArray);
        buttonsOrder = [castedArray mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"buttonsOrder : %@", buttonsOrder);
        CFRelease(cfArray);
        [castedArray release];
        castedArray = nil;
    }
    else {
        buttonsOrder = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *info in togglesInfo) {
            [buttonsOrder addObject:[info objectForKey:@"buttonIdentifier"]];
        }
    }
```

PS : NSLog() shows me that CFArray is returned well and is casted to NSArray and then NSMutableArray well too.

Any idea ?

Edit :

Here is how I modofy the array :

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
NSUInteger fromIndex = [fromIndexPath row];
NSUInteger toIndex = [toIndexPath row];
if (fromIndex == toIndex)
    return;
NSString *movedButtonId = [[[buttonsOrder objectAtIndex:fromIndex] retain] autorelease];
[buttonsOrder removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex];
[buttonsOrder insertObject:movedButtonId atIndex:toIndex];
```

}

Comment: Do you have a good reason why are you using CFPreferences instead of NSUserDefaults?  Also, where does the crash actually happen and what *is* the crash?

Comment: There's no reason to go through that casting/retaining. You can just take your mutable copy and then release the original `CFArray`.

Comment: I do. I'm not accessing the preferences of the current app, so I can't use NSUserDefaults (or I don't know how for a different app of the current one). The crash happens when I'm trying to access (delete or add values) the array. The crash makes the app exit.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: Nothing wrong with using `CFPreferences`. It's actually somewhat more flexible than `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I tried this too but it doesn't work too...

Answer (score 0):

If you crash while trying to *add* an object to a mutable array, that usually means you're attempting to add a nil object.  The only place (in your code snippet above) where I see you adding anything to your mutable array is in the case where you didn't get a valid "`cfArray`" from CFPreferences.  You should make sure "`[info objectForKey:@"buttonIdentifier"]`" isn't returning nil.

Check to make sure you're not throwing an exception.  Or if that's not it, say what your crash really is (it'll say in the Console log of Xcode).

Comment: In the case I didn't get a valid CFArray, everything works well and my app keep going, and [info objectForKey:@"buttonIdentifier"] is never nil. The crash appears only when I access an object from the array initialized from the CFPreferences function.

Comment: Error is 'signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5'

Comment: If you're accessing an object from the array that initialized from CFPreferences, that code isn't in your snippet up there.  Please modify your question to show that code where you access (add or delete) the mutable array.

Comment: instead of doing that wacky "`
NSString *movedButtonId = [[[buttonsOrder objectAtIndex:fromIndex] retain] autorelease];`" bit, make a copy of the string (e.g. "`NSString *movedButtonId = [NSString stringWithString: buttonsOrder objectAtIndex:fromIndex]];`" and insert *that* into your mutable array.  Also, make sure "`movedButtonId`" is not nil before attempting to insert it.